# Why doesn't input box shrink in width since we've fr as width for column

Tags: html, css

[image]

HI,

In above picture, as we can see, the input box doesn't shrink in width, even though the column is a grid with fr as widths of column, what is the exact meaning of fr and why doesn't the label shrink as well?

Comment: fr is a fractional unit. Therefore, if you have 3 columns set as grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr, each column should have 1/3 of the entire width. So if you do grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr), each has 1/4 of the entire width and so on.

Comment: Please copy and paste a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code to help people on stackoverflow to assist you.

Comment: My first guess is that the width of the input elements is set and is causing overflow. Html always tries to show content as much as it can.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't shown us some relevant info - like how the form is sized and ditto the upload-columns. Can you take the form and its related CSS and just one example of content of the two upload columns and make a runnable snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: Note: a real [mre] is often **not** a simple copy and paste. It requires some effort to make. (@BernardBorg)